# Is there any way to use VSCode on a chromebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, chromebook

I want to use VSCode on my chromebook, but I'm not sure if I can. Would there be any way to enable Linux or something to be able to use VSCode?

Comment: Not really a question for this site, and I would suggest trying Google first.

Comment: VS Code already had [a guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/12/03/chromebook-get-started) on how to use VS Code on Chromebooks. This guide is the first result from a simple Google search

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can**. It includes enabling Linux on your Chromebook. As it has already been covered in a [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/12/03/chromebook-get-started) written by VS Code itself, you can follow that [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/12/03/chromebook-get-started)